# Bootstrap Scrolling Nav Bar not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make it function properly, but it is not working on carousel area. It seems to be detecting my about and industry (carousel) sections to be the same. I am trying to separate the two but still believes that carousel area is in the about div section, which isnt.. Thank you!! Also I set the nav test link to carousel for testing.

```html
<!------------- navigation -------------->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
        <li class="hidden">
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#myCarousel">test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact1">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!---------- video ---------->

<div id="home"></div>

<video loop autoplay poster="links/._Aloha-Mundo.jpg" id="bgvid">
  <source src="links/eb%20vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
  <source src="links/eb_vid.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
<div class="logo">
  <img src="links/eb-logo-01.png" />
</div>

<!---------- about -------->
<div id="about">
  <div class="about-all container col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=""></div>
      <div class="eb-about col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <h1>About Eon-Blue</h1>
        <p>Based in Las Vegas, Nevada, Eon Blue is your complete branding technology solution. By putting a robust scope of capabilities together, we make sure each component is working with the other – all towards achieving your objectives. With web, information
          technology, marketing, software engineering and graphic design all moving in lockstep, our clients avoid the pitfalls of fragmentation...and enjoy the benefits of seamless integration.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="tech col-md-4">
        <img src="links/icons-01.png" alt="technology and consulting" class="compass">
        <h2>Technology &amp; Consulting</h2>
        <p>We’ve put together a team of professionals who are not only adept at what they do, but also great at working with clients, personally, to get the job done. We’re here to advise our clients. To educate them on new technologies and capabilities.
          And most of all, to hear their goals and objectives.</ br>
          We can create the innovative solutions that achieve them. We do our due-diligence before starting any project to make sure that all of the missing puzzles are put together before any development begins to take place on the canvas.</ br>
          Creating sustainable software is important to us and we make sure we get it right the first time.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="software col-md-4">
        <img src="links/icons-02.png" alt="software development">
        <h2>Software Development</h2>
        <p>No matter what your objectives, our experienced development team can create the software that helps you accomplish them. Eon Blue will tailor a solution specific to you, built from the ground up. Our approach is:</p>
        <ul class="sd-list">
          <li>Strategy-driven</li>
          <li>Free from open-source software</li>
          <li>We work closely with our analysts &amp; designers</li>
          <li>Grounded in best practices</li>
          <li>Maintaining the systems once they are up and running</li>
          <li>Testing the product in controlled, real situations before going live</li>
          <li>Reviewing current systems</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="data-services col-md-4">
        <img src="links/icons-03.png" alt="data">
        <h2>Data Services</h2>
        <p>Data is what moves the world. Yet many companies find the volume of data to be unwieldy, or sometimes downright unmanageable. We help you make sense of data so you can turn it into profits. Our full capabilities include:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Warehousing</li>
          <li>Scrubbing</li>
          <li>Validations</li>
          <li>Reports</li>
          <li>Conversions</li>
          <li>SRS reporting</li>
          <li>Management</li>
          <li>Mining</li>
          <li>Crystal reports...and more</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--------- carousel --------->
<section id="industries"></section>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="7" class=""></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="links/self-insured-groups.png" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Self Insured Groups</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="links/captive-insurance.png" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Captive Insurance</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="links/workers-comp.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Workers Compensation Insurance</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="fourth-slide" src="links/alternative-risk.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Alternative Risk</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="fifth-slide" src="links/property-and-casualty.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Property and Casualty</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="sixth-slide" src="links/reinsurance-and-excessInsurance.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Reinsurance and Excess Insurance</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="seventh-slide" src="links/Self-Funded-Health.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Self Funded Health</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="eight-slide" src="links/risk-management.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Risk Management</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Umm what do you want?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith just edited my post thank you

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is happening, I have replaced images on the placeholders.

The problem is that the relative link does not scroll the page to the carousel.

To solve the problem, remove `col-md-12` from `<div class="about-all container col-md-12">`. This class is not needed here, but adds an attribute `float: left;` to the block, which stands in front of the carousel. It caused the link leads to the place where the carousel has not yet appeared.

---

**Additional recommendations**

Do not use the section just like a bookmark. Wrap pieces of code into sections. The code will be clearer and more resistant to errors.

It seems necessary to replace `<div class="eb-about col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-6">` by `<div class="eb-about col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">`.

Use `<br />` or `<br>` instead of `</ br>`. And even better - to split a large paragraph into smaller paragraphs.

Slides have long descriptions. It would be better to hide them on small screens. I've added `hidden-xs` to them.

This code helps headers do not fall under the menu while scrolling:

```
#home, #about, #industries, #contact1 {
  margin-bottom: -70px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

---

**Check the result**

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#home, #about, #industries, #contact1 {
  margin-bottom: -70px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
#contact1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!------------- navigation -------------->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
        <li class="hidden">
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#industries">Carousel</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact1">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!---------- video ---------->
<section id="home">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200&text=Video" alt="">

    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=Logo" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section

<!---------- about -------->
<section id="about">
  <div class="about-all container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=""></div>
      <div class="eb-about col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <h1>About Eon-Blue</h1>
        <p>Based in Las Vegas, Nevada, Eon Blue is your complete branding technology solution. By putting a robust scope of capabilities together, we make sure each component is working with the other – all towards achieving your objectives. With web, information
          technology, marketing, software engineering and graphic design all moving in lockstep, our clients avoid the pitfalls of fragmentation...and enjoy the benefits of seamless integration.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="tech col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100&text=Icon%201" alt="">
        <h2>Technology &amp; Consulting</h2>
        <p>We’ve put together a team of professionals who are not only adept at what they do, but also great at working with clients, personally, to get the job done. We’re here to advise our clients. To educate them on new technologies and capabilities. And most of all, to hear their goals and objectives.</p>
        <p>We can create the innovative solutions that achieve them. We do our due-diligence before starting any project to make sure that all of the missing puzzles are put together before any development begins to take place on the canvas.</p>
        <p>Creating sustainable software is important to us and we make sure we get it right the first time.</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="software col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100&text=Icon%202" alt="">
        <h2>Software Development</h2>
        <p>No matter what your objectives, our experienced development team can create the software that helps you accomplish them. Eon Blue will tailor a solution specific to you, built from the ground up. Our approach is:</p>
        <ul class="sd-list">
          <li>Strategy-driven</li>
          <li>Free from open-source software</li>
          <li>We work closely with our analysts &amp; designers</li>
          <li>Grounded in best practices</li>
          <li>Maintaining the systems once they are up and running</li>
          <li>Testing the product in controlled, real situations before going live</li>
          <li>Reviewing current systems</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <div class="data-services col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100&text=Icon%203" alt="">
        <h2>Data Services</h2>
        <p>Data is what moves the world. Yet many companies find the volume of data to be unwieldy, or sometimes downright unmanageable. We help you make sense of data so you can turn it into profits. Our full capabilities include:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Warehousing</li>
          <li>Scrubbing</li>
          <li>Validations</li>
          <li>Reports</li>
          <li>Conversions</li>
          <li>SRS reporting</li>
          <li>Management</li>
          <li>Mining</li>
          <li>Crystal reports...and more</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--------- carousel --------->
<section id="industries">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="7" class=""></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200&text=Slide%201" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Self Insured Groups</h1>
            <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200&text=Slide%202" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Captive Insurance</h1>
            <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200&text=Slide%203" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Workers Compensation Insurance</h1>
            <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200&text=Slide%204" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Alternative Risk</h1>
            <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200&text=Slide%205" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Property and Casualty</h1>
            <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200&text=Slide%206" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Reinsurance and Excess Insurance</h1>
            <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200&text=Slide%207" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Self Funded Health</h1>
            <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200&text=Slide%208" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Risk Management</h1>
            <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="contact1">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <p>Phone</p>
    <p>E-mail</p>
    <p>Address</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200&text=Map" alt="">
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```